# Why won't my "Circle" program run?

Tags: java, constructor

I have been working on this for days and can't get the program to run. I have to name 3 fields, and utilize setRadius() getRadius(). I also must set and compute all fields in setRadius(). At first I had no main, but kept getting error. I included main, program compiles, but won't run. Please help.

```
public class Circle
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Circle myCircle = new Circle();

}
double radius;
double diameter;
double area;

public void Circle()
{
   radius= 1;
   diameter = radius * radius;
   area = Math.PI * radius * radius;

}
public void setRadius()
{
    radius = 1;
    diameter = radius * radius;
    area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);

}
public double getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}
public void display()
{
   System.out.println("The radius is " + radius);
   System.out.println("The diameter is " + diameter);
   System.out.println("The area is " + area);
}

}
```

Comment: `public void Circle()` is not a constructor. Remove the void keyword and then call `myCircle.display()` in your main.

Comment: FYI,`radius*radius` is NOT `diameter` of a circle

Comment: "Program compiles,but won't run" ,Of course it does!

Comment: take a look at OOP on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone said in comments your constructor is not valid.
your setRadius shoud get an parameter
and call display after construction

```
public class Circle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle myCircle = new Circle();
    myCircle.display();
}

double radius;
double diameter;
double area;

public Circle() {
    radius = 1;
    diameter = radius * radius;
    area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
}

public void setRadius(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    diameter = radius * radius;
    area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);

}

public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

public void display() {
    System.out.println("The radius is " + radius);
    System.out.println("The diameter is " + diameter);
    System.out.println("The area is " + area);
}
```

}

Comment: yes you are right diameter is 2 * r   and so area is 2 * r *pi

Comment: pi * r² is area okok^^

Comment: Thank you. I changed to 2 * radius

Comment: As you see you have to change twice once in your constructor and once in your setRadius. Therfore it would be better to call setRadius(1) in your constructor !

Answer (score 0):

add `myCircle.display();` to main.

Answer (score 0):

Main is the entry point of your program, whatever you include in it will run. Your program is running it's just not doing anything (except creating a circle). If you want the program to display those messages you need to call `display()` inside main.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Circle myCircle = new Circle();
   myCircle.display();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. But only doing you make here is creting new object.
Add some more operations for your object.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Circle myCircle = new Circle();
    myCircle.setRadius();
    myCircle.display();
}
```

UPD: Also you have some mistakes:

1. diametr = 2 * radius (not radius * radius)
2. public void Circle() - is a function, not constructor. It's bad practice to use methods with the same name as contructor. So if you want it be a constructor remove 'void'
3. It will be more flexible if you will use setRadius method like that:

```
    public void setRadius(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
        diameter = 2 * radius;
        area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println`? How is the method caller supposed to know that an illegal argument was passed? Parse STDOUT? Surely you mean `throw new IllegalArgumentException`...

Comment: Yep. You are write. I was a little bit lazy to use it. Because it seems that author of question is in start of his path as programmer and maybe doesn't know about exceptions.

Comment: Then don't add a check at all. There is no point is teaching a learner the worst possible habits from day 1.